# Eco with statement if

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, partial-views, eco

It's Eco, the problem is it should add button just for some models(backbone) in partial, but the statment if not worked.The variables are accessible, but the owner.id a is string and current_user.id is a number.

```
<% if @owner?.id is current_user.id: %>
    <div class="info-add">
       <button class="button secondary tiny radius">
           <i class="fi-plus"></i>
           Add
       </button>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which actually summarizes your question.

Answer (score 1):

Eco uses CoffeeScript as the template language and in CoffeeScript, `is` and `==` become `===` in the JavaScript version. JavaScript's [strict equality operator (`===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) doesn't do the type conversions that `==` will do so `'6' === 6` is false even though `'6' == 6` is true.

You say that:

> the `owner.id` a is string and `current_user.id` is a number

so `@owner.id is current_user.id` will always be false.

If your client code is generating the `id` as a string then it is broken and you should fix it. If your server is sending `@owner.id` as a string then your server is broken and you should fix your server to send out the correct JSON; if you can't fix the server code then you could add a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method to your model to fix it for you:

```
parse: function(response) {
    if(response.id)
        response.id = +response.id // or parseInt(response.id, 10) if you prefer
    return response;
}
```